# How Bulgarians use the definite article in English

Tags: definite-articles

I have a friend from Bulgaria who tends to use the definite article "the" too often. Does anyone know Eastern European languages enough to help me explain to him the rule in English? The example I received today is "the Western civilization":

> the ideology behind the fight against “cultural Marxism” is that 
>   we need to defend the Western civilization, because in this way, we
>   are defending Christianity. That is, that the survival of Christianity
>   depends on the survival of the Western civilization. "

I consulted [this](https://web.archive.org/web/20090302101520/http://www.fortunecity.com:80/bally/durrus/153/gramch16.html).

Comment: Slavic languages have no indefinite or definite article so it is impossible to reference those languages to help explain English.

Comment: Perhaps you should be happy that he didn’t say “the Marxism” or “the Christianity”.     :-)    ⁠

Comment: It could be that he is overcompensating. Bulgarian doesn't have a definite article, and English does, but doesn't use it always. So maybe they just use it always even in instances when English wouldn't.

Comment: Slavic and many other languages have no interest in articles; they use noun cases where Frankish or Germanic people use verb tenses. Alone, enough to stop lazy Westerners trying Central, never mind East European tongues.

Having met hundreds of Slavics I assure you they readily understand the rules. The problem is, many if not most teachers fail to see, let alone explain the place of nouns in Western languages.

"The" in "we need to defend Western civilisation…" matters not.

Whether any Western language needs any article depends on context.

Comment: I gave up trying to explain the rules governing articles when I realized that I can't come up with reliable rules. Specifically, I can't explain why I can catch **a** cold, or **the** flu, or pneumonia (without an article). Nor can I explain why, after catching pneumonia, I (an American) was in **the** hospital whereas a Canadian would (as far as I know) have been in hospital.

Answer (score 1):

There are definite articles in Bulgarian language, although there aren’t officially any indefinite - we just use ‘one’ for singular. Here’s brief explanation of how it is used - https://www.google.com/amp/s/blazingbulgaria.wordpress.com/2012/06/06/definite-articles/amp/

Now you see why I wrote articles, not just one article. Not only they are several but we use them a lot in Bulgarian language, and I think that’s the reason of overused def article in English by Bulgarians.

Answer (score 1):

Contrary to what other users have so confidently asserted, Bulgarian has a definite article. Bulgarian and Macedonian are the only Slavic languages that do; in this they resemble other Balkan languages like Greek and Albanian.

The reason your friend overuses the definite article in English is simply that it's used more often in Bulgarian than in English. However, it would be difficult to explain "the rule" that regulates article usage in English to him seeing as it's irregular. Why don't words like "life," "civilisation" and "nature" take a definite article in English when "world," "afterlife" and "universe" all do? It takes a lot of practice to master grammatical subtleties like this.

If you can understand what your friend is trying to say, there's no need to explain anything to him. He'll develop an intuition for articles and prepositions on his own.

Source: I'm a native speaker of Bulgarian.

Answer (score 0):

There is a good article describing the definite (and other) articles at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Article_(grammar) . If you look at the list of languages with definite articles, almost all come from one of two geographic regions: Polynesian, and Southern and Western IndoEuropean/Afro-Semitic. This is a contiguous area on the map despite it covering two language families and not covering all of IndoEuropean - specifically it leaves out the Slavic languages that include Bulgarian. The definite article in some languages such as Greek and Arabic is, I believe, fairly logical - you put in an article if it is definite. So you can imagine a Bulgarian learning this fairly quickly. In fact the definite article is so common in Arabic that English speakers think it is part of the noun. That is why many nouns from Arabic such as *algebra*, *alcohol*, *alchemy* start with *al*. *Al* is simply the definite article but Europeans thought it was part of the noun.

But there is an inner group of languages, again in a neat geographical area - Germanic and Celtic, and to some extent Romance, that have more complicated rules that are hard for anyone (including Bulgarians) to understand. You don't need an article with something definite if it is obviously definite - so no article with names - you don't say *the David*, and you don't need one with *Western Civilization* because the word *Western* makes it clear that we are talking about one specific *civilization*. Similarly instead of saying *the head of the king*, we say *the king's head*, with no article before *head*. I don't need to go on as there is plenty of discussion on this site about the definite article.

The main point is that the definite article in Western Europe (particularly the North West) is unusually complicated, especially for someone who doesn't have any at all.

Comment: Greek is not related to Slavic languages, even though the alphabets look similar. The Saints, Cyril and Methodios, were Greek. They devised the Cyrillic alphabet as part of their ministry to the Slavs. In the Greek language, if I am speaking about David to a third person, I say "O David", that is, the David.